# Handling huge number of fields in scalatra model

Tags: scala, cassandra, scalatra

I'm building a rest api using scalatra and cassandra. My cassandra data model is having 1000+ fields. I need to read these fields into scalatra middleware and do a lot of json manipulation as per business logic. What are the ways in which I can automatically/easily map the cassandra fields -> scalatra object -> JSON response?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Cassandra 2.2 added JSON support**
You can use `SELECT JSON`

> The SELECT statement has also be extended to support retrieval of rows in a JSON-encoded map format. The results for SELECT JSON will only include a single column named [json]. This column will contain the same JSON-encoded map representation of a row that is used for INSERT JSON. For example, if we have a table like the following:

Let you schema be

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    age int,
    state text
);
```

You can use

```
SELECT JSON * FROM users;
```

The results will look like this:

```
{"id": "user123", "age": 42, "state": "TX"}
```

or you can use

```
SELECT JSON id, writetime(age), ttl(state) as ttl FROM users;
```

Output :

```
{"id": "user123", "writetime(age)": 1434135381782986, "ttl": null}
```

Source : http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-2-json-support